# Kotlin String.format() is centering my text

Tags: string, kotlin, format

As I understood it, if you did something in Kotlin like `String.format("%3d", 4)` (arbitrary example put illustrates my point) you would get a string like `"  3"` (padded to the left by two spaces). For some reason, when I do that in Kotlin, it is instead centering the string (so I get something like `" 3 "`). Any clue why this could be happening? Everything I'm reading says right-aligned is the default, but that's not happening for me.

Example:

```
hp.text = String.format("%-10s\t%4d\t%-5s\t%4d\t%-5s\t%4d", "HP:", pokemon.hp, "EVs:", pokemon.hpEv, "IVs:", pokemon.hpIv)
```

For context, this info is read in from the output of a Lua script reading the memory of a Desmume emulator playing a Pokemon game. Basically this string is in 6 sections. First the name of the stat, then the stat itself. Followed by "EVs:" and the number of EVs for that stat, and "IVs:" and the number of IVs for that stat. For now, between left aligning the text (which does work for some bizarre reason) and putting tabs (`\t`) between everything, I've gotten it look... acceptable. But what's happening here is that the numbers seem to be centered within their section of the string. Here's a picture of what this ends up looking like.

[Dragonite Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8E5l.png)

I would have expected the numbers to be right-aligned so that the 1s place in each of them lines up, but that's not happening for some reason.

[Link to github repo](https://github.com/leggettc18/PokemonOverlay/tree/layout-changes)

UPDATE: I've also tried left-aligning everything by adding `-`after all the percent signs and that makes all the numbers left-aligned with each other. It's just so baffling to me that I can't seem to get it to right-align for the life of me. [Dragonite again, left-aligned this time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VdzR.png)

UPDATE 2: I figured it out, put my answer down below. A key point that I didn't realize when I posted this (I adopted this codebase, didn't create it from scratch), was that it was using tornadofx, possibly with a default non-monospaced font.

Comment: When I put `String.format("%3d", 4)` in my Kotlin project then `"  3"` is printed as expected. Try it on some empty project yourself.... Only thing I can imagine wrong can be that your string is not actually a `kotlin.String`, or you have some custom extension function `fun String.format` which is imported in your code - so you do not use the standard `format` function at all...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this is being printed into a label in a GUI, but even then its one label with a formatted string with several variable substitutions and each one is getting centered (unless I supply the - character to left-align it). It's an overlay that reads the output of a lua script which reads Pokemon information from a game running in Desmume. I'll add a sample to my question.

Comment: @EduardTomek I added an example of what I'm talking about to my question and a link to the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I think the issue ended up being the default font set by tornadofx's GUI elements. I suspect the reason was a non-monospaced font causing the spaces to be smaller than the characters in such a way that they ended up looking centered. I fixed it by setting a Monospaced font in the style I was using for the text I wanted to be formatted.

```
font = Font.font(java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED, 10.0)
```

You may need to import javafx.scene.text.Font.

Here's how it looks now. Not a huge fan of the font so I might look for a better looking monospaced font, but this at least has the formatting I want.

[Flaafy with properly right-aligned stats.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdPhY.png)

Will be on the lookout for any other potential better answers.